# Python: Writing multiple variables to a file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm fairly new to Python and I've written a scraper that prints the data I scrap the exact way I need it, but I'm having trouble writing the data to a file. I need it to look the exact same way and be in the same order as it does when it prints in IDLE

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

year_entry = raw_input("Enter year: ")

week_entry = raw_input("Enter week number: ")

week_link = requests.get("http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/scoreboard/?week=" + week_entry + "&phase=2&season=" + year_entry)

page_content = BeautifulSoup(week_link.content)

a_links = page_content.find_all('tr', {'class': 'game link'})

for link in a_links:
        r = 'http://www.sports.yahoo.com' + str(link.attrs['data-url'])
        r_get = requests.get(r)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r_get.content)
        stats = soup.find_all("td", {'class':'stat-value'})
        teams = soup.find_all("th", {'class':'stat-value'})
        scores = soup.find_all('dd', {"class": 'score'})

        try:
                game_score = scores[-1]
                game_score = game_score.text
                x = game_score.split(" ")
                away_score = x[1]
                home_score = x[4]
                home_team = teams[1]
                away_team = teams[0]
                away_team_stats = stats[0::2]
                home_team_stats = stats[1::2]
                print away_team.text + ',' + away_score + ',',
                for stats in away_team_stats:
                        print stats.text + ',',
                print '\n'
                print home_team.text + ',' + home_score +',',
                for stats in home_team_stats:
                        print stats.text + ',',
                print '\n'

        except:
                pass
```

I am totally confused on how to get this to print to a txt file the same way it prints in IDLE. The code is built to only run on completed weeks of the NFL season. So if you test the code, I recommend year = 2014 and week = 12 (or before)

Thanks,

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a file you need to build up the line as a string, then write that line to a file.

You'd use something like:

```
# Open/create a file for your output   
with open('my_output_file.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    ...
    # Your BeautifulSoup code and parsing goes here
    ...
    # Then build up your output strings
    for link in a_links: 
        away_line = ",".join([away_team.text, away_score])
        for stats in away_team_stats:
            away_line += [stats.text]
        home_line = ",".join(home_team.text, home_score])
        for stats in home_team_stats:
                home_line += [stats.text]

        # Write your output strings to the file   
        csv_out.write(away_line + '\n')
        csv_out.write(home_line + '\n')
```

This is a quick and dirty fix. To do it properly you probably want to look into the `csv` module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html))

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of your output I agree with Jamie that using CSV is a logical choice.

But since you're using Python 2, it's *possible* to use an alternate form of the print statement to print to a file.

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

> print also has an extended form, defined by the second portion of the
>   syntax described above. This form is sometimes referred to as “print
>   chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the >> must
>   evaluate to a “file-like” object, specifically an object that has a
>   write() method as described above. With this extended form, the
>   subsequent expressions are printed to this file object. If the first
>   expression evaluates to None, then sys.stdout is used as the file for
>   output.

Eg,

```
outfile = open("myfile.txt", "w")
print >>outfile, "Hello, world"
outfile.close()
```

However, this syntax is not supported in Python 3, so I guess it's probably not a good idea to use it. :) FWIW, I generally use the file write() method in my code when writing to files, except that I tend to use `print >>sys.stderr` for error messages.